# Laravel 5: Auth::id() returns NULL in AppServiceProvider.php

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am trying to set a global variable in the `AppServiceProvider.php` file in Laravel 5. However, I cannot query a database which uses the currently logged in user ID. **The Auth::id() returns null.**

here is my code;

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;


class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    public function boot()
    {
        $cnv_count = Conversation::where('receiver_id', Auth::id())->count(); // This Auth::id() here returns null

        view()->share(['cnv_count' => $cnv_count]);
    }


    public function register()
    {

    }
}
```

It doesn't return any error but when I try printing the the Auth::id() in the `AppServiceProvider.php` file, it always returns `NULL`.

what am I doing wrong here?

Appreciate the help guys.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're using an updated Laravel 5 version. You may want to consider this kind what i'm using to detect an authenticated user.

add this above your class.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Authenticated;
```

call this inside the class method.

```
Event::listen(Authenticated::class, function ($event) {
           $this->data['auth'] = $event->user;
        });
```